# help me problem in my shell script

Tags: bash

I need back from 2 or 3 to 1 after print error ??

```
 1      echo -e "program set defulte home dirctory /home/admin/$un"
        echo -e "DO you want use defulte home dirctory? Yes=1 & NO=2"
    read -a hd1
    case $hd1 in
            1)
             hd=`/home/admin/$un` #40
             echo -e "your home dirctory $hd1 " ;;
            2)
             echo -e "Please insert name your home dirctory between 1 to 10 character:"
            read -a hda
            len1=${#hda}
            if [ "$len1" -eq "$ze" ];then
             echo "There is no Argument home dirctory" # error message
 2          exit
            fi
            if [ "$len1" -ge "$te" ];then #50
             echo "The argument home dirctory  maximum 10 alphanumeric" # error message
 3          exit     
            fi
            hd=`/home/admin/$hda`;;
            *) echo " You have selected wrong Choice!!!" ;;
    esac
```

Comment: You probably want to use a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a while-loop to keep the question running and break out of it when done as shown below

```
while :; do  # : evaluates to true, so "while true; do ...; done"
    echo "Choose A or B"
    read answer
    case "$answer" in
      [Aa]) # match case-insensitive A
        echo "A was chosen"
        break    # leave the while-loop
        ;;
      [Bb]) # match case-insensitive B
        echo "B was chosen"
        break    # leave the while-loop
        ;;
      *)
        echo "Please choose A or B only"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: thank you """ but in choose 2=no in my ask i m check argument enter from user between 0 to 10 character if wrong back to return choose 1 or 2

Comment: It looks like you're using Google Translate, I can hardly understand you. Carefully look at my code, you should be able to figure out how to implement the logic. `break` will prevent from asking a question again.